# Cartid is a required field error in custom payment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, payment

I am using ccavenue payment module in my site. For guest users payment is working fine, it's redirected to the payment page. But for logged in users I am getting this error while placing the order. I checked in headers cartid is passing to the payment. My magento version is Magento ver. 2.1.11

> http://test.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/billing-address

```
cartId is a required field
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: This code is already present. I solved in different way

Comment: Good to know that you resolved it, it would be better if you can share your findings here in answer, so that I would be helpful for others in future

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1443

It was issue in early release of Magento 2. But after reporting it has been fixed.

**Override the file in any custom module**

```
vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/CarrierFactory.php
```

Find the function `createIfActive` after the line

`\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,`

Add `$storeId`

You function would be like this:

```
public function createIfActive($carrierCode, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/active',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    ) ? $this->create(
        $carrierCode,
        $storeId
    ) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was VERTEX Integrated Address Cleansing that was causing this. Not sure why. Turned off the sett